# MongoDB - Request for Moving average

Tags: php, mongodb, nosql

I use a MongoDB database with the following structure

```
"_id": ObjectId("5531214ff31ca6e6368b54e6"),
"d_second": NumberLong(51),
"d_minute": NumberLong(5),
"d_hour": NumberLong(17),
"d_day": NumberLong(17),
"d_week": NumberLong(16),
"d_month": NumberLong(4),
"d_year": NumberLong(2015),
"amount": 1.30005,
```

How can a build a request which will return an array providing for each second the average of the "amount" value for the last 30 seconds for example

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean for each value from the `d_second` field of each document or for each second (long polling)?

Comment: @chridam Imagine there would be only a "timestamp" field instead of "d_second", "d_minute" etc.... I would like to calculate the moving average of the 30 last "d_second" (one document per second is inserted), so the results would have the timestamp and the moving average corresponding to the average of the last 30 "amount" value (last 30 timestamp) (Is that clear?)

Comment: This is well-covered in answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151042/moving-averages-with-mongodbs-aggregation-framework/52138825#52138825

Answer (score 1):

You can use [aggragation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db-collection-aggregate)

```
db.Testing.aggregate([{ $project: 
        { date: 
            { "$concat": [
                    { "$cond": [
                        { "$lte": [ "$d_month", 9 ] },
                        { "$concat": [
                                "0",
                                { "$substr": [ "$d_month" , 0, 2 ] },
                        ]},
                        { "$substr": [ "$d_month", 0, 2 ] }
                    ]},
                    " ", 
                    { "$cond": [
                        { "$lte": [ "$d_day", 9 ] },
                        { "$concat": [
                                "0",
                                { "$substr": [ "$d_day" , 0, 2 ] },
                        ]},
                        { "$substr": [ "$d_day", 0, 2 ] }
                    ]},
                    " ", 
                    { "$substr": [ "$d_year", 0, 4 ] },
                    " ", 
                    { "$cond": [
                        { "$lte": [ "$d_hour", 9 ] },
                        { "$concat": [
                                "0",
                                { "$substr": [ "$d_hour" , 0, 2 ] },
                        ]},
                        { "$substr": [ "$d_hour", 0, 2 ] }
                    ]},
                    ":", 
                    { "$cond": [
                        { "$lte": [ "$d_minute", 9 ] },
                        { "$concat": [
                                "0",
                                { "$substr": [ "$d_minute" , 0, 2 ] },
                        ]},
                        { "$substr": [ "$d_minute", 0, 2 ] }
                    ]},
                    ":", 
                    { "$cond": [
                        { "$lte": [ "$d_second", 9 ] },
                        { "$concat": [
                                "0",
                                { "$substr": [ "$d_second" , 0, 2 ] },
                        ]},
                        { "$substr": [ "$d_second", 0, 2 ] }
                    ]},
            ]},
            'amount' :1 
        }
    },
    {'$group' : {'_id' : '$date' ,'avg' : {'$avg' : '$amount'}}},
    {'$sort' : {'_id' : -1}},
    {'$limit' : 30}
])
```

Remember this will give you the average for last 30 time-stamps and not 30 seconds.

Also it would be better to use a `Date` or a `time-stamp`  object instead of different keys. In that case you can match for documents last 30 seconds and then do a grouping on date/time-stamp to get the average.

Comment: It looks like your solution it only giving one moving average as a result, for one second (correct me if I am wrong), and i would like the result to be a table with all the moving average of all the seconds. Is that possible somehow?

Comment: Have a look at [moving-averages-with-mongodbs-aggregation-framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151042/moving-averages-with-mongodbs-aggregation-framework).

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151042/moving-averages-with-mongodbs-aggregation-framework/52138825#52138825