# Compute Moving Averages from a Self Join

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following query that computes the moving average on a MySQL table:

```
SELECT m1.x AS x, m1.y AS y, AVG(m2.y) AS average
FROM measured_signal AS m1
JOIN measured_signal AS m2 ON (m2.x BETWEEN m1.x - 5000 AND m1.x + 5000)
WHERE m1.x BETWEEN 5000 AND 15000 AND m2.x BETWEEN 0 AND 20000
GROUP BY m1.x
```

It works just fine, but now I am migrating to MongoDB and I need to perform the same operation.

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151042/moving-averages-with-mongodbs-aggregation-framework/52138825#52138825) that is quite similar but doesn't cover my specific case.

So far I have written down the following pipeline:

```
db.getCollection("measured_signal").aggregate([
  { $match: {x: { $gt: 0, $lte: 20000 } } },
  { $sort: { x: 1 } },
  { 
    $group:{
      _id: null,
      rows: { 
        $push: { x: "$x", y: "$y" }
      } 
    } 
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      rows: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$rows",
              cond: {
                $gte: ["$$this.x", {$subtract: ["$$this.x", 5000]}],
                $lte: ["$$this.x", {$add: ["$$this.x", 5000]}]
              }
            }
          },
          in: {
            x: "$$this.x",
            y: "$$this.y",
            average: { $avg: "$$this.x" },
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind:  "$rows" },
  { $match: {x: { $gt: 5000, $lte: 15000 } } }
],{allowDiskUse: true});
```

but it doesn't work.

Should I try something completely different? Or what should I change in this? Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

To better understand the problem, I'm adding an example of input data

```
{x:3628, y: 0.1452},
{x:7256, y: 0.1358},
{x:10884, y: 0.1327},
{x:14512, y: 0.1285},
{x:18140, y: 0.1256},
{x:21768, y: 0.1268},
{x:25396, y: 0.1272},
{x:29024, y: 0.1301},
...
```

and the desired output, considering a window size of 5000:

```
{x:7256, y: 0.1358, average: 0.1379}, // average computed on rows between 2256 and 12256
{x:10884, y: 0.1327, average: 0.1323}, // average computed on rows between 5884 and 15884
{x:14512, y: 0.1285, average: 0.1289}, // average computed on rows between 9512 and 19512
{x:18140, y: 0.1256, average: 0.1270}, // average computed on rows between 13140 and 23140
{x:21768, y: 0.1268, average: 0.1265}, // average computed on rows between 16768 and 26768
{x:25396, y: 0.1272, average: 0.1280}, // average computed on rows between 20396 and 30396
...
```

Comment: Seeing your test case documents and actual vs. desired results could help identify a solution.

Comment: I've added an example of input and output data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your SQL and what I see as the *"literal interpretation"* to a MongoDB statement I actually only get **three** results from the *eight* documents posted in the question.

The statement I see as identical is actually:

```
db.measured_signal.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "x": { "$gt": 5000, "$lt": 15000 } } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "measured_signal",
    "let": { "x": "$x", "y": "$y" },
    "pipeline": [
      { "$match": {
        "x": { "$gt": 0, "$lt": 20000 },
        "$expr": {
          "$and": [
            { "$gt": [ "$x", { "$subtract": [ "$$x", 5000 ] }] },
            { "$lt": [ "$x", { "$add": [ "$$x", 5000 ] }] }
          ]
        }
      }},
    ],
    "as": "results"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$results" },
  { "$group": {
     "_id": "$x",
     "y": { "$first": "$y" },
     "average": { "$avg": "$results.y" }
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
     "_id": "$$REMOVE",
     "x": "$_id"
  }},
  { "$sort": { "x": 1 } }
]).map(({ x, y, average }) => ({ x, y, average }))
```

And the result:

```
    {
            "x" : 7256,
            "y" : 0.1358,
            "average" : 0.1379
    },
    {
            "x" : 10884,
            "y" : 0.1327,
            "average" : 0.13233333333333333
    },
    {
            "x" : 14512,
            "y" : 0.1285,
            "average" : 0.12893333333333334
    }
```

If you work though its pretty logical.

Aggregation pipelines in MongoDB *should* typically start with a `$match` condition. This is basically the `WHERE` clause in a declarative SQL statement, but in an aggregation pipeline this "filter" condition is done first. Notably the `JOIN` is not yet done so the initial [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) only looks at the initial ( or `m1` ) view of the collection/table.

The next thing would the the `JOIN`. This is done via [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/), and here we can actually create an *expression* on which to "join" on being equal to the conditions presented in SQL. Here the second part of the `WHERE` is included in the `$match` within the `pipeline` argument of [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). This actually means another "filter" on the foreign documents ( in this case a *"self join"* ).

The other thing to note is the `let` argument in the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/), along with the [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) in the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) for the inner pipeline. This allows values from the initial collection ( or `m1` ) to be compared with the *foreign* collection ( or `m2` ). As you can see the expressions inside the [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) are done a little differently, since these are actual *"aggregation expressions"* of the comparison operators for [`$gt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/gt/) and [`$lt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lt/) and these versions return a `Boolean` value on the compared values. In short we make *variables* referring to values from the initial document and compare those to the values in the foreign collection to determine part of the *"join"* condition.

The output of [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) is always an "array" added into the initial document containing the matched *foreign* results. This is always an array, even if there is only one result. The new field in the initial document containing this array is named by the `as` argument. To be literal to the SQL, a `JOIN` would produce *denormalized* output where there are **many** copies of the parent document to each foreign *child*. The literal translation of this is [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), but alternately you could skip that step and just change the line with the `$avg` later to:

```
 "average": { "$avg": { "$avg": "$results.y" } }
```

On to that "average", the next thing is of course [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), where just like in the SQL you want to `GROUP BY` the `x` value from the initial collection document ( still called `x` by MongoDB ) and of course MongoDB is a bit more *literal* than SQL in this regard so you **must** use an accumulator for anything not in the `GROUP BY` or `_id` of the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) statement. This means using the [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator as the appropriate "accumulator" for the `y` value.

The "average" is of course obtained by [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/), either straight on the singular *denormalized* values produced from [`$unwind][5]`, or on the "array" content first and then per "grouped document". Hence the demonstrated second example where [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) is specified twice for those two purposes.

Since [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) requires it's `GROUP BY` key to be named `_id` by convention, if you want this renamed you would need the [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) stage. That's how you make MongoDB return the names you want from an aggregation pipeline, but personally I would probably stick with the `_id` in the returned result and just rename via a `.map()` or similar action. Demonstrated also on the above listing since an [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) and other [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) operations actually would keep the order of defined fields from the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) output. Basically meaning that `x` would be the *last* field in output documents rather than the first.

So the last parts really are *cosmetic* and you need not do them just to see the desired result. And of course the output from [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) does not have a default order like a `GROUP BY`, so you want a [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) at the end of the actual pipeline execution, or optionally sort the resulting documents after translation to an array if the result is small enough and you prefer that.

> **NOTE** Since the `pipeline` expression in [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) is in fact a full *pipeline* in itself, you could and in fact probably *should* perform the [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) operation **before** returning the result array in `as`. This however would not actually change the fact that it still **must** return an array, but the results would be significantly less and far safer in the case of a "large join" result, since you only return the **one** number needed.
>
> Since this is *"still"* an array, it would not change the need for either the `$unwind` or the *double `$avg` statement as demonstrated. It's just *nicer* to not return a large array of things you don't really need for the end result.

---

Just to show these are in fact the same things, I have your SQL code running in a self contained listing and another running the statement on MongoDB. As you can see, both produce the same results.

NodeJS code just for convenience of the author to run against two engines.

**SQL Listing**

```
const { Op, DOUBLE, SMALLINT } = Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const logging = log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));
const sequelize = new Sequelize('sqlite:dbname.db', { logging });

const MeasuredSignal = sequelize.define('measured_signal', {
  id: { type: SMALLINT, primaryKey: true },
  x: DOUBLE,
  y: DOUBLE
}, { freezeTableName: true });

(async function() {

  try {

    await sequelize.authenticate();
    await MeasuredSignal.sync({ force: true });

    let result = await sequelize.transaction(transaction =>
      Promise.all(
        [
          {x:3628, y: 0.1452},
          {x:7256, y: 0.1358},
          {x:10884, y: 0.1327},
          {x:14512, y: 0.1285},
          {x:18140, y: 0.1256},
          {x:21768, y: 0.1268},
          {x:25396, y: 0.1272},
          {x:29024, y: 0.1301}
        ].map(d => MeasuredSignal.create(d, { transaction }))
      )
    );

    let output = await sequelize.query(
      `
        SELECT m1.x AS x, m1.y AS y, AVG(m2.y) as average
        FROM measured_signal as m1
        JOIN measured_signal as m2
        ON ( m2.x BETWEEN m1.x - 5000 AND m1.x + 5000)
        WHERE m1.x BETWEEN 5000 AND 15000 AND m2.x BETWEEN 0 AND 20000
        GROUP BY m1.x
      `, { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT });

    log(output);


    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e)
    } finally {
      process.exit()
  }

})()
```

Output:

```
"Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result"
"Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `measured_signal`;"
"Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `measured_signal` (`id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, `x` DOUBLE PRECISION, `y` DOUBLE PRECISION, `createdAt` DATETIME NOT NULL, `updatedAt` DATETIME NOT NULL);"
"Executing (default): PRAGMA INDEX_LIST(`measured_signal`)"
"Executing (7c7d0f4d-719a-4b4c-ad6a-5d5c209b8fa1): BEGIN DEFERRED TRANSACTION;"
"Executing (7c7d0f4d-719a-4b4c-ad6a-5d5c209b8fa1): INSERT INTO `measured_signal` (`id`,`x`,`y`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5);"
"Executing (7c7d0f4d-719a-4b4c-ad6a-5d5c209b8fa1): INSERT INTO `measured_signal` (`id`,`x`,`y`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5);"
"Executing (7c7d0f4d-719a-4b4c-ad6a-5d5c209b8fa1): INSERT INTO `measured_signal` (`id`,`x`,`y`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5);"
"Executing (7c7d0f4d-719a-4b4c-ad6a-5d5c209b8fa1): INSERT INTO `measured_signal` (`id`,`x`,`y`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5);"
"Executing (7c7d0f4d-719a-4b4c-ad6a-5d5c209b8fa1): INSERT INTO `measured_signal` (`id`,`x`,`y`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5);"
"Executing (7c7d0f4d-719a-4b4c-ad6a-5d5c209b8fa1): INSERT INTO `measured_signal` (`id`,`x`,`y`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5);"
"Executing (7c7d0f4d-719a-4b4c-ad6a-5d5c209b8fa1): INSERT INTO `measured_signal` (`id`,`x`,`y`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5);"
"Executing (7c7d0f4d-719a-4b4c-ad6a-5d5c209b8fa1): INSERT INTO `measured_signal` (`id`,`x`,`y`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5);"
"Executing (7c7d0f4d-719a-4b4c-ad6a-5d5c209b8fa1): COMMIT;"
"Executing (default): SELECT m1.x AS x, m1.y AS y, AVG(m2.y) as average\n        FROM measured_signal as m1\n        JOIN measured_signal as m2\n        ON ( m2.x BETWEEN m1.x - 5000 AND m1.x + 5000)\n        WHERE m1.x BETWEEN 5000 AND 15000 AND m2.x BETWEEN 0 AND 20000\n        GROUP BY m1.x"
[
  {
    "x": 7256,
    "y": 0.1358,
    "average": 0.13790000000000002
  },
  {
    "x": 10884,
    "y": 0.1327,
    "average": 0.13233333333333333
  },
  {
    "x": 14512,
    "y": 0.1285,
    "average": 0.12893333333333332
  }
]
```

**MongoDB listing**

```
const { Schema } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
const opts = { useNewUrlParser: true };

mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('debug', true);

const signalSchema = new Schema({
  x: Number,
  y: Number
});

const MeasuredSignal = mongoose.model('MeasuredSignal', signalSchema, 'measured_signal');

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri, opts);

    await Promise.all(
      Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k,m]) => m.deleteMany())
    );

    await MeasuredSignal.insertMany([
      {x:3628, y: 0.1452},
      {x:7256, y: 0.1358},
      {x:10884, y: 0.1327},
      {x:14512, y: 0.1285},
      {x:18140, y: 0.1256},
      {x:21768, y: 0.1268},
      {x:25396, y: 0.1272},
      {x:29024, y: 0.1301}
    ]);

    let result = await MeasuredSignal.aggregate([
      { "$match": { "x": { "$gt": 5000, "$lt": 15000 } } },
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": MeasuredSignal.collection.name,
        "let": { "x": "$x", "y": "$y" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": {
            "x": { "$gt": 0, "$lt": 20000 },
            "$expr": {
              "$and": [
                { "$gt": [ "$x", { "$subtract": [ "$$x", 5000 ] } ] },
                { "$lt": [ "$x", { "$add": [ "$$x", 5000 ] } ] }
              ]
            }
          }}
        ],
        "as": "results"
      }},
      { "$group": {
        "_id": "$x",
        "y": { "$first": "$y" },
        "average": { "$avg": { "$avg": "$results.y" } }
      }},
      { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }
    ]);

    result = result.map(({ _id: x, y, average }) => ({ x, y, average }));

    log(result);
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect()
  }

})()
```

Output:

```
Mongoose: measured_signal.deleteMany({}, {})
Mongoose: measured_signal.insertMany([ { _id: 5cb7158c50641f1837a7b272, x: 3628, y: 0.1452, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cb7158c50641f1837a7b273, x: 7256, y: 0.1358, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cb7158c50641f1837a7b274, x: 10884, y: 0.1327, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cb7158c50641f1837a7b275, x: 14512, y: 0.1285, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cb7158c50641f1837a7b276, x: 18140, y: 0.1256, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cb7158c50641f1837a7b277, x: 21768, y: 0.1268, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cb7158c50641f1837a7b278, x: 25396, y: 0.1272, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5cb7158c50641f1837a7b279, x: 29024, y: 0.1301, __v: 0 } ], {})
Mongoose: measured_signal.aggregate([ { '$match': { x: { '$gt': 5000, '$lt': 15000 } } }, { '$lookup': { from: 'measured_signal', let: { x: '$x', y: '$y' }, pipeline: [ { '$match': { x: { '$gt': 0, '$lt': 20000 }, '$expr': { '$and': [ { '$gt': [ '$x', { '$subtract': [Array] } ] }, { '$lt': [ '$x', { '$add': [Array] } ] } ] } } } ], as: 'results' } }, { '$group': { _id: '$x', y: { '$first': '$y' }, average: { '$avg': { '$avg': '$results.y' } } } }, { '$sort': { _id: 1 } } ], {})
[
  {
    "x": 7256,
    "y": 0.1358,
    "average": 0.1379
  },
  {
    "x": 10884,
    "y": 0.1327,
    "average": 0.13233333333333333
  },
  {
    "x": 14512,
    "y": 0.1285,
    "average": 0.12893333333333334
  }
]
```