# How to query average of fields for each five documents?

Tags: mongodb, moving-average

I am new to mongoDB, I have a simple document structure in MongoDB as shown(but have millions of documents with different values). Here `timestamp` is in unix format and is generated at every 1 minutes.for example, for 5 minutes, collection will have 5 different documents with different timestamp,

```
{
  a:12,
  b:52,
  c:15,
  timestamp: 15603418700
} 
{
  a:22,
  b:21,
  c:14,
  timestamp: 15603418760
} 
{
  a:9,
  b:23,
  c:32,
  timestamp: 15603418820
}
```

Now, I wish to query average of each a,b, and c for each 5 minutes or say 5 documents. That is, I need output something like

```
{
  Avg_of_A : [15.3, 16.6, 16.4],
  Avg_of_B : [20.3, 21.4, 23.0],
  Avg_of_C : [18.9, 17.5, 15.6],
}
```

Here, `15.3` is average of value of `a` for first 5 documents and `16.6` is average of value of `a` for next 5 documents and so on....

Note : 1. This is just dummy output, I just need output in such format so that I can print the data for average of each 5 minutes(documents)

Comment: Your use case doesn't seem fit for a database. Opt for some real-time streaming platform.

Comment: @RajatGoel Why mongoDB can't handle such use case? can you suggest any better database?

Comment: I didn't MongoDB can't handle, I said database (all). The problem should be targeted at real-time. You will be receiving data from some source. Before storing data in MongoDB and then aggregating last 5 records at DB level, better to keep aggregating beforehand only.

Comment: Ok I got it, you want me store avg of 5 minutes in database while inserting new documents. which real time streaming platform you  were talking about?

Comment: You can use any like spark/flink. Or you can write your own code (do everything in memory) in application from where you are persisting data in MongoDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called "Moving Average". [Moving averages with MongoDB's aggregation framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25151042/moving-averages-with-mongodbs-aggregation-framework) offers solution in MongoDB.

SQL databases with Window functionality can do that more elegant way: https://www.essentialsql.com/sql-puzzle-calculate-moving-averages/

Comment: Thanks for introducing me with Moving average...Can you please update your answer with mongoDB Query,I am having certain issue as in my case date is stored in `unix` format